# Solve for x value given y = 0 in a random effects model in r

Tags: r, lme4

I have a random effects model that looks at the mean bias of the results from a numerical water temperature model given changes to a parameter, roughness. Roughness is the x variable, mean_bias is the y variable, and the location in the stream (1:9) is the random effect variable:

```
lmer_mb <- lmer(mean_bias ~ roughness + (1|location), data = W3T, REML=FALSE)
```

[image: Plot of the lmer]

I've tried using approx () to find the roughness value when mean_bias = 0:

```
xval <- approx(roughness = lmer_mb$fitted,  mean_bias = lmer_mb$roughness, xout = 0)$mean_bias
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Error in approx(roughness = lmer_mb$fitted, mean_bias =
>   lmer_mb$roughness,  :    unused arguments (roughness = lmer_mb$fitted,
>   mean_bias = lmer_mb$roughness)

I also want to plot the xval (once I figure it out) on my plot, and was going to adapt the code that I found in another question on stackoverflow:

```
xval <- approx(x = fit$fitted.values, y = x, xout = 30)$y
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: No, use `predict` and `solve` to inverse it. Also, you use a linear model, but the relationship looks non-linear. Consider transforming your y-values or use a mgcv GAM.

Comment: Thank you! I can't figure out the syntax for the solve() function. My predict function looks like this: newdata <- data.frame(mean_bias=c(-0.25,0,0.25))
predict(lmer_mb, newdata=W3T).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the approach I needed to solve this problem. I needed to load the package

```
library(merTools)
```

Then I used the wiggle function to generate a new data frame around the area where I wanted to solve for x:

```
 opt2 <- wiggle(data=W3T, var="roughness", values = seq(0.05,0.1,0.001))
```

Then, I filtered opt2 for the values I wanted and turned them into a list:

```
sub.opt2 <- filter(opt2,mean_bias == "0")
sub.opt3 <- list(sub.opt2)
```

And finally, found the average roughness using the draw() function:

```
opt.roughness <- draw(lmer_mb, type = 'average', varList = sub.opt3)
opt.roughness
```

My solution was based on the code I found here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/merToolsIntro.html